# F# LINQ lastOrDefault unix Epoch

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, f#, query-expressions

I am learning LINQ with F#. I want to know how to use lastOrDefault.
If I have a SQL Server data table called Days, which store some date, I want to write a query to select the last date of the table, if there is no record, I want to return the unixEpoch, which is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

```
let lastDate =
    query {
          for day in days do
          lastOrDefault
          }
```

Let me know how to return unixEpoch, if there is no record in the data table.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lastOrDefault` operator here returns the last date if the data table is not empty. Otherwise, it returns the default value of [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx), which happens to be `DateTime.MinValue`.

Since you cannot alter this default value, it's better to check whether the query result is the default value and return outside the query:

```
let lastDate =
    let d =
       query {
               for day in days do
               lastOrDefault
          }
    if d = DateTime.MinValue 
    then new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    else d
```

However, returning Unix Epoch isn't the F#-ish way of handling exceptional cases. It's clearer to return `None` if there is no record in the datatable, and it's also easier to process this `option` value to deal with an unexpected situation:

```
let lastDate =
    let d =
       query {
               for day in days do
               lastOrDefault
          }
    if d = DateTime.MinValue then None else Some d

match lastDate with
| None -> (* Process the exceptional case *)
| Some d -> (* Do something with d *)
```